# Getting Max value out of date column for each month

Tags: date

I have a table in SQL server with Countries, Number of Issues, and Datetime column in format (2017-05-26 07:03:54.640). Now I want to get the Number of issues for each country for each month and for each month if I have multiple entries on a single day for a country then I want to report only the last status for numbers.

For Ex: 
Country NumIssues   Date

IN   24  2017-05-26 04:03:54.640
IN   27  2017-05-26 04:05:54.640
IN   21  2017-05-26 04:07:54.640
IN   25  2017-05-27 04:03:54.640

Then Output should look like
Country NumIssues   Date    YR  Mon

IN  25  2017-05-27 04:03:54.640     2017    May

I am trying to group by Country and I want the latest value of date for each month. So I have extracted Year and month values to separate columns in my query but I am still getting multiple values for each region because I need to include NumIssues in group by (can't do sum(NumIssues) here as I want NumIssues for the most recent date for each month of that country)

Can someone please help me out in this?

Comment: You have to add more information. Are you talking about some code problems? Though nobody can help yet.

Comment: A table where? In a file? In a database? In a spreadsheet? Why BZ and not IN? Why 25? etc...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my post with more details